# Mapping Indoor Floor Plan into OSM-XML for Use in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, indoor-positioning-system

I am currently working on a project at my home university to create an infrastructure-less indoor navigation iPhone application. I have a couple of questions regarding IndoorOSM and hope that experts here can steer me towards the right direction.

1. Given an indoor floor plan, how can I make use of JOSM to map it into OSM-XML format? I understand that the floor plan will be represented as nodes, ways, tags and relations with each node having a lat-lon value. As the indoor space I would like to map is located in Singapore where there is little existing mapping work done, I am not sure where to accurately place the floor plan in JOSM before modelling (the buildings are non-existent). The thing is, if I start modelling on a wrong location, the lat-lon values generated in the OSM-XML file will be way off from the lat-lon values in actual real world space, right? In that case I don't think I will be able to make use of the magnetometer to identify where the user is currently at on the map...
2. In the OSM wiki, it was mentioned that nodes represent a geospatial point and ways are simply a collection of 2-2000 nodes and can be used to represent an area. Pardon my ignorance, but how can I know what's the physical size/area of this "point" or node?
3. Other than IndoorOSM, is there an easier way to convert an indoor floor plan into something that my application can understand and use easily to allow navigation? I seen a project known as roodin on youtube but I'm not sure how they did the mapping ([link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTZFRDBdQck)).

Answer (score 3):

I'm also working on app with similar functionalities. What I understand is:

1 - When mapping a building you should mapping with correct lat/long. It shouldn't be difficult to get building coordinates if you can go there and check coordinates with a smartphone with GPS. With you can't go there, it's more difficult. Maybe ask someone to do that helps you. But, to start drawing your floor plan, you don't need coordinates. you can do that after finish your drawing

2 - When use JOSM to drawing, it show (in status bar) the length of your way

3 - Currently, I'm sticking with IndoorOSM. I liked the way they reuse nodes, ways and relations to draw a floor plan. That's my recommendation